Git Gui Windows does not call pre-hook
I'm using Git git version 2.45.2.windows.1 and I implemented a prepare-commit-msg hook locally to my repository. Here is an MWE:
#!/bin/sh
# prepare-commit-msg hook
echo $0
filename=$(date | sed 's/[^0-9]//g') # date
touch $filename.txt # create a new file
exit 0

When committing from the console with git commit -m "My message", the hook gets called and I see the name of the hook.
.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg

But when I do a commit using the Git Gui, the hook does not get called.
Does anyone have an idea of what is happening?


Are you sure it is not running? Where do you expect to see the output in the GUI? For me it is run but the output not displayed because there is no real place to display it. Add exit 1 at the end of the script and you will see that the hook is run and Git Gui is complaining and display the error when it is opened (and with your echo)

Indeed the hook gets called. There was another reason why I thought it hadn't been called. Your tip gave me the right direction where to look. For completeness I updated the example above to create a new file every time, the hook gets called. Thanks for your help.

@SebastianRV I'm having the exact same issue, but in my case it really isn't being called.
Did you modify some other git setting(s) as well?
I changed my prepare-commit-msg hook contents to the same as yours. When running it as a command git commit -m "blabla"the file gets created. When attempting to commit through git gui it does not
